# How to SELECT INTO tableB which name is @tableB * FROM @tableA?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am creating a stored procedure which has to create a table which name depends on input variable. For temporary results I have declared a table variable:

```
declare @tableA TABLE(
column1,
column2,
..
)
```

The output table name depends on the user's input so I have declared another variable

```
declare @tableB varchar = ...
```

In the end the temporary results have to be stored into table which name is @tableB so in the stored procedure I have tried to write the following statement:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @tableB + ' FROM @tableA'
exec(@sql)
```

which is not correct. Does anyone know how to insert values from table variable into table which name is variable?

Comment: am I missing something here? @tableB is a normal table right? So why can't you use a simple dynamic insert query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use table variables here, try to use temporary tables.
create table #tableA( ...

For more information: [link text](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/temp_tables_vs_variables_p1.aspx)

> create table #A(
>     c1 int,
>     c2 int
>   );
>
> insert into #A values (1,2);
>
> insert into #A values (3,4);
>
> declare @sql varchar(max);
>
> declare @tableB sysname = '##tableB';
>
> set @sql = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @tableB + ' FROM #A';
>
> Print @sql;
>
> exec (@sql);
>
> go
>
> select * from ##tableB;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `@tableB` already exists, first guess would be to try:

```
SET @sql =
    'INSERT
    (
        col1,
        col2
    )
    INTO ' + @tableB + ' 
    SELECT 
    (
        col1, 
        col2
    )
    FROM
        @tableA'
```

This isn't syntax-checked, so watch out!

If @tableB doesn't exist, why does its name need to come from the user?